# Ionic $state.go does not show menu button

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm learning ionic-framework and I have created a small app in to fetch a list of movies (via a asp.net mvc 5 web api 2 web service). Now, when I add a new movie, I want to redirect the user back to the list of movies (on succes). The problem I'm facing is that when the list is shown, in my menubar you can see only a back button. What I want is that the user only sees the side-menu button. This is what I have in my controller:

```
moviesApp.controller('AddMovieCtrl', function($scope, $http, dataFactory, $state){
        $scope.isEditable = function () {
            return $scope.edit && $scope.edit.movie;
        };

         $scope.cancel = function () {
            $scope.edit.movie = null;
        };

        $scope.movie = {};

        $scope.save = function () {
            alert($scope.movie.Title);
            dataFactory.create($scope.movie).success(function (response) {
                $scope.movie = null;
                $state.go('app.movies'});

            });  
        };
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Putting this before $state.go should fix your issue

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
  disableBack: true
});
```